# serverless starting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handler'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, request, serverless

how are you doing!?

I'm having some problems when trying to run a local lambda function (I have already installed all the global node dependencies: serverless/serverless-offline/serverless-python-requirements/handler/prototype).

This is the stack trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ramir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\handler-runner\python-runner\invoke.py", line 76, in <module>

    module = import_module(args.handler_path.replace(os.sep, '.'))
  File "C:\Users\ramir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handler'
```

Could it be a problem with my installed python? I tried to update all the global dependencies and reinstall them but it is still displaying the error.

Comment: can you share your lambda code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.